# Background page lifecycle and page action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm totally newbie in JavaScript and in plugin development for Google Chrome. I'm trying to create my first extension for it. My aim is have a [page action](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html) on wikipedia pages which show simple JS alert on each click. My code listed below:

```
// manifest.json
{
    "name": "My Plugin",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "description": "My first expirience in plugin development for Google Chrome browser",

    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Action Title"
    },

    "background": { 
        "scripts": ["background.js"] 
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}

// background.js
// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);

// Called when the url of a tab changes.
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  // Show action only for wikipedia pages
  var regex = /wikipedia.org/gi;
  if (tab.url.match(regex)) { 
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(onClickListener);
  }
};

function onClickListener(tab) {
    alert('Clicked!!!');
}
```

The problem is that alert showing on the screen multiple times. And after each page reload it will shows two times more. For example:

- open page
- click my plugin icon
- alert shows 2 times
- go to next page
- click icon
- alert shows 4 times

and so on...

But i want show alert only one time per click. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are repeatedly adding the listener... you only need to add it once when the plugin first loads

Comment: Could you explain where I can do this? How to catch the moment when the plugin first loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initially add your listeners when the document loads. You'll want to add your listeners after the DOMContentLoaded event has been fired:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
    //chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(onClickListener); //might need to put this here, it's been a while since I've done a chrome extension, but if you do then just put your conditional for the regex in your onClickListener function
});

    // Called when the url of a tab changes.
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  // Show action only for wikipedia pages
  var regex = /wikipedia.org/gi;
  if (tab.url.match(regex)) { 
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(onClickListener);
  }
};

function onClickListener(tab) {
    alert('Clicked!!!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it show me the direction where to look for what I need. In my case page content doesn't metter I need only page link. Therefore I need another document event something like onPageLoadingStarted.